# Failed to get data from localhost using php in android

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im new at Android. I'm trying to fetch some data from localhost server. My query is running perfectly on phpMyAdmin But I facing error in api. I have very little knowledge about Php so did not get what the issue is.

Code:

```
public function saveUserProgress($user_id,$course_id,$topic_id,$quiz_marks){

        $output = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_progress (user_id, course_id, topic_id,quiz_marks)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            user_id=?, course_id=?, topic_id=?, quiz_marks = quiz_marks + ?");

        $output->bind_param("iiii",$user_id,$course_id,$topic_id,$quiz_marks);

        if($output->execute()){
            return  PROGRESS_SAVED;
        }else{
            return ERROR_OCCUR;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
{"error":true,"message":403}
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

Comment: so will i pass these 4 variables again ?@Dharman

Comment: @Dharman 4 variables in insert statement is same as 4 variables in On Duplicate Key Update statement

Comment: Which is what is confusing me. What is your unique key?

Comment: user_id and course_id is set unique as same user not have same course twice @Dharman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If as you said your unique key is `user_id` and `course_id` then you do not need to update them on duplicate key. You only need to update the remaining 2 values. Together with the 4 you wanted to add it makes 6 placeholders, so you need to bind 6 variables.

```
$output = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_progress (user_id, course_id, topic_id,quiz_marks)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        topic_id=?, quiz_marks = quiz_marks + ?");

$output->bind_param("iiiiii", $user_id, $course_id, $topic_id, $quiz_marks, $topic_id, $quiz_marks);
```